# Prompt from collection_selection not displayed in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have a `collection_select` as below. What I want is to display the `prompt` value on page load and not the `id` of the object. But now it displays the value of the `id` of the `f` object of the form on page load.

How can I change it so that as soon as the page loads the `prompt` value is displayed and the other `id` values are shown when the `collection_select` is clicked?

```
<%= f.collection_select(:id, Animal.all, :id, :id, {include_blank: 'Select animal'}, selected: params[:id]) %>
```

I tried this also:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:id, Animal.all, :id, :id, {include_blank: 'Select animal'}, selected: params[:id]) %>
```

This time `Select animal` is shown at the top when `collection_select` is clicked but the `id` of the present `Animal` object is displayed on page load. In the first case `prompt` value is not displayed anywhere. How can I change it?

Comment: Both your variant are identical

Comment: This part `selected: params[:id]` marks as selected one of options, usually we need it to display previously selected and saved options. Why do you use it here?

Comment: I did a mistake while saving the question I guess. I got it working. My apologies for the late reply. This is the working code: `collection_select(:animal, :id, Animal.where.not(id: params[:id]).select(:id), :id, :id, prompt: true, include_blank: 'Select Animal'`

Comment: Yes. I did not have to use `selected: params[:id]`. My mistake in reading the documentation.

Comment: Please, add your answer to the question. It is better move it from comments to separate post

Answer (score 1):

You can try following for it,

```
<%= f.collection_select(:id, Animal.all, :id, :id, include_blank: 'Select animal', selected: Animal.find(params[:id])) %>
```